# I need software for small library

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, collection-manager, books

I'm looking for a Windows program to list all the names, authors, year of publication, etc. of my books, with good search options.

I would like to fill all my books, authors, year of publication, etc. into a software which then I can look up easy. Just like a public library or university library which there is a big software for all the items of the library. Since I have a small library about 400 books, CDs, DVDs, research papers, etc. So, I need a software to arrange all my items to be easy to look for.

This software should have the following requirement:

1. Free of charge (gratis)
2. Working on Windows 7 platform.
3. Only for one user (personal use: maybe a family would use it, but it is not for many users)

Comment: What are you willing to pay for it? Did you misuse the tag open-source where you meant gratis? Please [edit] yor question.

Comment: Clarifying what Jan asked, do you mean "open-source" or "free-of-charge" (gratis) when you ask for "free-source"?

Comment: Is it going to be used to be multiple  users or single user ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [BiblioteQ](https://biblioteq.sourceforge.io/index.html)? It seems like something that could fit your needs (although, granted, it might be a bit very feature rich, but it does what you want it to nevertheless):

- it is free and open source,
- > it enables cataloging of books, dvds, journals, magazines, music cds, photograph collections, and video games,
- runs on Windows,
- you can have one user or multiple, your choice.

As I said before, it might have features that you do not need and won't use, but according to your description, it sounds like it can fit.